# Toeplitz tridiagonal matrix with $0$s on main diagonal and $1$s on sub/superdiagonal has distinct eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, tridiagonal-matrices, toeplitz-matrices

$$\begin{pmatrix}0&1&&&\\ 1&\ddots&\ddots&&\\ &\ddots&\ddots&\ddots&\\ &&\ddots&\ddots&1\\ &&&1&0\end{pmatrix}$$

has distinct eigenvalues. Why?

Clearly, the eigenvalues should be reals. How to show they are distinct? It seems hard to factor the eigenpolynomial.

Comment: The stronger [statement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tridiagonal_matrix#Eigenvalues) holds "*a real symmetric tridiagonal matrix has real eigenvalues, and all the eigenvalues are distinct if all off-diagonal elements are nonzero*", which wikipedia attributes [to](https://www.amazon.com/symmetric-Eigenvalue-problem-Beresford-PARLETT/dp/0138800472) *Parlett, B.N. (1980). The Symmetric Eigenvalue Problem. Prentice Hall, Inc*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, consider any Hermitian tridiagonal matrix $H\in M_n(\mathbb C)$ with an entrywise nonzero super-diagonal. If $H$ has a repeated eigenvalue $\lambda$, then $\operatorname{rank}(H-\lambda I)\le n-2$. (You may diagonalise $H$ to see this.) But this is impossible because the top-right $(n-1)\times(n-1)$ submatrix of $H-\lambda I$ is a nonsingular bidiagonal matrix. Hence all eigenvalues of $H$ are distinct.

Comment: much simpler and clearer than mine!

Answer (score 5):

Googling for eigenvalues and tridiagonal matrices led me to [this MO post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/131527/eigenvalues-of-symmetric-tridiagonal-matrices) which then links to [this paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0024379599001147?via%3Dihub):

> *Kulkarni, Devadatta; Schmidt, Darrell; Tsui, Sze-Kai*, [**Eigenvalues of tridiagonal pseudo-Toeplitz matrices**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/S0024-3795(99)00114-7), Linear Algebra Appl. 297, No. 1-3, 63-80 (1999). [ZBL0939.15002](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0939.15002).

The answer to your question follows from Section 2 of this paper. The additional links below are to the relevant sections of Wikipedia.

The characteristic polynomial of your $n\times n$ matrix is basically the $n$th Chebyshev polynomial of the second kind. I illustrate this (for $n=4$ below, only for easy typing), by expanding the determinant along the bottom row and then the rightmost column:
$$p_n(\lambda) := 
\left|\begin{matrix}
-\lambda & 1  
\\
1 & -\lambda & 1 
\\&1 & -\lambda & 1 
\\&&\color{red}1 & \color{darkgreen}{-\lambda }
\end{matrix}\right|=\color{darkgreen}{-\lambda} p_{n-1} - \color{red}1\left|\begin{matrix}
-\lambda & 1  
\\
1 & -\lambda &  
\\& 1& 1  
\end{matrix}\right|  = -\lambda p_{n-1}(\lambda)-p_{n-2}(\lambda)$$
writing $-\lambda = 2x$ and $U_n(x):=p_n(-2x)$, we find
$$ U_n(x) = 2x U_{n-1}(x) - U_{n-2}(x)$$
Which is the [three-term recurrence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials#Recurrence_definition) for the Cheybyshev polynomials of the second kind. Combining with the initial data that is directly verified $U_2(x) = p_2(-2x) = 4x^2-1$ and $U_3(x) = 8x^3-4x$, $U_n$ are precisely these polynomials.

The roots of the Chebyshev polynomials of the second kind are [well known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials#Roots_and_extrema) to be $\cos(k\pi/(n+1)),\ k=1,2,\dots,n$: this follows from the formula $U_n(\cos \theta)=\sin((n+1)\theta)/\sin(\theta)$. This immediately gives the eigenvalues as $$-2\cos(k\pi/(n+1)),\quad k=1,2,\dots,n$$  (The minus sign can be dropped by symmetry.)

So one reason why the roots are distinct is because cosine is injective on $(0,\pi)$.

Comment: (+1) This is also identity $(19)$ at https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ChebyshevPolynomialoftheSecondKind.html, though without an obvious attribution.

Comment: @dxiv thanks for the extra reference. The paper I quoted does not claim this to be their own work, but I am not so familliar with the history of these things...